# why i am having problem while installing HAXM in android studio?

Tags: android, haxm

getting error that Vt-x is not enabled . i enabled virtualization technology but error still remains same.
i have no antivirus installed except windows defender.
i tried manually installing from SDK tools.

Comment: the hyper v is also disabled